# Difference between Web Services and Web API

Tags: web-services, web, asp.net-web-api

I have already gone through to the couple of tutorials to find the answer of this question but I did not find out the exact one. Everyone discusses about the api which we generally use with our project as a dependency but I always ask this question in context of web only.

What do you think about it?

Is there any difference between these two terms : Web Services and Web API

Comment: Duplicate.  Not a bad question, but its already discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya definitely there is difference between both of this frameworks.
In .net web services are built using wcf framework and web api are built using webapi framework.
If you are beginner i would say that web api is nothing but advanced and well developed form of web services.
web api are built as they can serve any type of devices in any format(content-type) of data.

Actually webapi vs web service is such concept that is difficult to explain but very easier to understand by doing some mock labs or experiments.

Comment: should not be answered as it is already asked and answered as well.

Comment: Thanks Ravindra :)